# Crystal Reports Typecast Year stored as Char in DB

Tags: sql, casting, crystal-reports

I have a char(4) in a DB that I need to compare to a numeric range parameter in my report. Specifically the char represents a year of birth and my report asks the user to search for a range of years (e.g., 1950-2013)

How can I use the record selection to typecast the value in the DB, then compare it to the range to generate the query?

I tried using:

```
ToNumber(dbValue) >= Minimum(parameter) and ToNumber(dbValue) <= Maximum(parameter)
```

Comment: You tried the above code and what was the problem?

Comment: Well, for some reason it is ommitted from the SQL query generated. It seems like it just skips that line completely

Answer (score 1):

Crystal is not generating that portion of the SQL query because it's not valid SQL syntax, it's Crystal syntax. What you're doing would work, it would just be inefficient since the client instead of the server would have to do that record filtering. (Because of this, a good rule to follow is to use very few, if any, Crystal functions in the record selection formula, because Crystal usually can't translate them to SQL).

Instead, do the type conversion in a SQL Expression. For example:

```
-- SQL Expression {%YearConversion}
-- Cast using valid PL/SQL syntax
to_number("table"."YearString")
```

Now, since you have the conversion done in valid SQL, you can use that in your record selection formula without worrying about Crystal having to do the filtering.

```
// Sample line from record selection formula
{%YearConversion} >= {?StartDate} and {%YearConversion} <= {?EndDate}
```